# What is the proper way of setting headers in a URLConnection?

Tags: java, header, urlconnection

My code is like the following:

```
URLConnection cnx = address.openConnection();
cnx.setAllowUserInteraction(false);         
cnx.setDoOutput(true);
cnx.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
InputStream is = cnx.getInputStream();
```

Is it ok if I set the headers before I get the `InputStream`? Will my header be sent, or will the server see the default `URLConnection`'s user-agent ( if any ) ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The headers **must** be set prior to getting the `InputStream` to have any affect - an `IllegalStateException` will be thrown if the connection is already open.

As far as the `User-Agent` header specifically, it should be sent if it has been set.

See the [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) JavaDoc.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question, the code is correct. The moment getInputStream(), an HTTP get is sent to the target server.

A side-note on user-agent, if you don't set it, URLConnection will send the default one anyway, which is:

```
User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_24 (varies depending on your java version)
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd advise against using low-level constructs such as URLConnection. There are plenty of libraries for sending HTTP requests, with the most prominent being Apache HTTP Client.

Comment: (should be comment, does not answer question)

Comment: Apache HTTP Client is discouraged and deprecated in the Android Framework. Google encourages the use of HttpURLConnection.