# How to send HTTP GET request to proxy with Android

Tags: android, sockets

I need to send GET request to proxy, with custom headers and then read response?

ex:

GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: en-US

User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Host: www.google.com

Connection: Keep-Alive

Some-field: sdasdas

How to sent such request to somesite.com:sopeport ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) is exactly what you need and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331538/what-is-the-proper-way-of-setting-headers-in-a-urlconnection) for sample usage. I know that the last one's for J2SE, but they should support the same interface.