# Setting Request Header in java

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts, struts-1

Is there any way to modify or set-header of request inside action class? I want to modify it or you can say i want to put flag inside request Header just like we put values in 'attribute' and parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/how-to-modify-request-headers-in-a-j2ee-web-application/). But it's quite dirty solution. Are there really no other ways to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Request parameters returned from the servlet are unmodifiable `Map`. You cannot add/delete content returned from request (via servlet).

In order to set a flag, my suggestion is to store it in a session, and on another action, retrieve the flag & delete it from session.

Comment: it means i can only get data from request. one way data movement

Comment: Yes, since a request is data sent from client to server. Think of it as client sending you genuine info. If we had opportunity to manipulate header requests, then anybody can spoof it through code. Wait, it is possible, but for Servlet, the container shouldn't allow this.

Comment: what you mean by container? i m working in struts-1 and attempting to modify the request in action class

Comment: You are running on Struts action in a servlet container (Tomcat), that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need to wrap the original request into a request class containing the change you wish to have.

It might be better design to have the request parameters parsed earlier in processing to such objects that make more sense to your application logic, and then set the state of those objects in the place where you now would like to modify the original header.

Comment: can you give me example how can i wrap my request?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to open a URL connection using Java,
you can something like this [What is the proper way of setting headers in a URLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331538/what-is-the-proper-way-of-setting-headers-in-a-urlconnection)

If you can make requests with a browser,
You can use this Firefox plugin to add/modify any number of request headers.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends on what problem you're trying to solve.

One of your comments suggests you're trying to test; if this is the case you have two basic options:

1. Use a mock request (unit-style testing).
2. Change the header from the client (integration-style testing).

For testing from real clients, set headers on the client side.

For mocking client interactions, you should be using some form of mock. [StrutsTestCase](http://strutstestcase.sourceforge.net/), for example, provides [MockStrutsTestCase](http://strutstestcase.sourceforge.net/api/servletunit/struts/MockStrutsTestCase.html) (outside container) and [CactusStrutsTestCase](http://strutstestcase.sourceforge.net/api/servletunit/struts/CactusStrutsTestCase.html) (inside container) classes allowing easy manipulation of request properties and characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more details. It sounds like you want to manipulate the request header once the server has received the request. I'm not sure I understand why you would want to do that. Modifying the response headers make sense. But not the request.

Comment: actually i want to simulate the flow. the header is set by third party module. but on local i want to test the reflection of that that is why i was trying to set Header of request

Answer (score 0):

I think they only clean way you can do this is via an [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html)

Just override getHeader, getHeaders, getHeaderNames and you are good to go.