# Can't read in HTML content from valid URL

Tags: java, url, io, network-programming, inputstream

I am trying out a simple program for reading the HTML content from a given URL. The URL I am trying in this case doesn't require any cookie/username/password, but still I am getting a **io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403** error. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? (I know there are similar question in SO, but they didn't help):

```
    import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.io.IOException;
public class urlcont {
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
  URL u = new URL("http://www.amnesty.org/");
  URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
  uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
  uc.connect();
  InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();
  int b;
  File f = new File("C:\\Users\\kausta\\Desktop\\urlcont.txt");
  f.createNewFile();
  OutputStream s = new FileOutputStream(f);
  while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
    s.write(b);
  }
}
catch (MalformedURLException e) {System.err.println(e);}
catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(e);} 
}
}
```

Comment: why `int b` and not `char b` ?

Comment: Ummm, no idea. Why indeed? Java is driving me nuts...

Comment: Did you take this code from the net?

Comment: Not exactly, Oreilly's `Java IO`. I guess, the `read` method returns the byte read as an unsigned byte.

Comment: Ohh.. sorry, i din't see **Stream**. Then its right. :)

Comment: Your code is working for me...

Comment: Strange, it wasn't working for me until I changed the `http` in the URL to `https`. Dunno why, the site doesn't require it, I can jolly well visit it with `http`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can fetch the URL in a browser, but not via Java, that indicates, to me, that they are blocking programmatic access to the page via user-agent filtering. Try setting the user-agent on your connection so that your code appears, to the webserver, to be a web-browser.

See this thread for help on that: [What is the proper way of setting headers in a URLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331538/what-is-the-proper-way-of-setting-headers-in-a-urlconnection)

Comment: I tried the code and it is working for me. I only changed the local file path. I have the full html in the file now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a permission problem:

> A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server refuses to allow the requested action

Comment: Why is the server blocking me? I can open it jolly well in my browser. Do I need to send some browser headers?

Comment: nope you just are using the wrong protocol, you are getting the file directly, but as far as i understood you want the html-output only. look up `http-request`. the server doesn't want to show you the source code, but he will give the browser the result as he does only request the output and not the file itself

Answer (score 0):

you are not doing anything "wrong", the server you are trying to access is blocking your request, as you are not allowed to access the file

Http-Error 403 means Forbidden --> the remote server blocks the request.

check if you need to give authentification to access the document you want and in that case provide it with the request ;)